# Image doesn't fill whole page

Tags: html, css

My (simplifed) html and css look like this:

```css
@keyframes animatedBackground {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 100% 0;
  }
}
 
 *{margin:0;padding:0;}/*added as requested*/
.background-image {
  background-image: url("http://wallpapercave.com/wp/UoQbFHi.jpg");
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  left: 0;
  bottom:0; /*added as requested*/
  right:0;
  top:0; /*added as requested*/
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 160%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="background-image"></div>
```

Aparently

```
webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
```

Doesn't work here?
Anyway, my problem is that on the browser I'm using, this gives a weird spacing on top (for some reason)

EDIT:
Still doesn't work the space on top is still there, result:
[image]

Comment: Try body {margin:0}

Comment: Have you removed default margin and padding of body and html?

Comment: try `*{margin:0;padding:0;}`  or `body{margin:0;padding:0;}`

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, I've tried that, it worked, but only for the code without the `webkit-filter: blur(5px);` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try the following:**

set `body as margin:0;padding:0`

and `.background-image as top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0`

Change `webkit-filter` into `-webkit-filter`

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
 }
@keyframes animatedBackground {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 100% 0;
  }
}
.background-image {
  background-image: url("http://wallpapercave.com/wp/UoQbFHi.jpg");
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  left: 0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 160%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="background-image"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: But does it work if you uncomment the `webkit-filter` part?

Comment: I don't know if this is a browser issue, but yours also as a white space at the top...

Comment: @Safirah Please view the full page or you test in your page(local or server). But here the full page view working fine. :-). Let me know once you get some problem in your local or server system.

Comment: What browser are you using? I've done what you said and I'm still seeing the huge white gap

Comment: @Safirah Not a browser issue. It is default behavior for blur.

Comment: @MathsRkBala, omg, thank you, that was exactly what I was thinking! Any ideas on how to avoid this?

Comment: ie11, Chrome(version 53.x), Firefox(version 49.x)

Comment: I've figured out that the solution is usng negative values in `margin-top`. Anyways your answer was the most helpful one. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In most of the browsers, there is a default margin and padding in `user-agent-stylesheet` that comes with browser.

Not all but some of the browsers allow you to customize that css file but it is always easy to explicitly add your css for body element in your web page like

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
       .....
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Body part will invoke the inner divisions, So make sure about the Body Margins, If we set body `margin:0px` then that will touch the top of the browser.

Try this code inside your CSS Code,

```
body{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```